# String parameter not automatically converting into bytes32 when used with form

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

I have a solidity function which looks like this-

```
function issueCertificate(address _recipient, bytes32 _certi_name)
```

When I call the function using truffle console, I am able to run it using-

```
issueCertificate("0x0213e3852b8afeb08929a0f448f2f693b0fc3ebe", "random")
```

But when I run it using web3 and forms with same data in string format, it gives error-

> Error: Given parameter is not bytes: "random"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using web3.js version 1.0, you can use:

`web3.utils.asciiToHex("random")`

See the documentation here:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#asciitohex

Answer (score 5):

Extend answers above to more complete picture:

Conversion from string to bytes32

```
web3.utils.fromAscii
```

Conversion from bytes32 to string

```
web3.utils.toUtf8()
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491123/string-parameter-not-automatically-parsing-into-bytes32-when-used-with-form

Try:

```
issueCertificate("0x0213e3852b8afeb08929a0f448f2f693b0fc3ebe", bytes32("random"))
```

Basically, wrap the string with bytes32()

Edit, missed the call being made from Web3 try:

```
issueCertificate("0x0213e3852b8afeb08929a0f448f2f693b0fc3ebe", web3.fromAscii("random"))
```

Basically, in Web3 wrap the string with web3.fromAscii()